# How to route with Devise with subdomains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm working on a Rails apps that uses an `app` subdomain. For example, if a user visits my application at `www.mysite.com` and logs in, they should be redirected to `app.mysite.com/` (which should be the articles#index page as it's the authenticated root). For some reason, when I try to log in, it signs me in ok, but redirects me to my main root route, rather than the authenticated root route. Here is my `routes.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { 
    sign_up: 'signup', 
    sign_in: 'login',
    sign_out: 'logout' 
  }

  authenticated :user do
    constraints subdomain: 'app' do
      get '/topics', to: 'topics#index'
      get '/articles', to: 'articles#index'
  
      root to: 'articles#index', as: :authenticated_root
    end
  end

  root 'home#index'
end
```

Do I need to adjust the devise set up so that it's aware of the `app` subdomain? If so, how?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Devise just redirects to the root path:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || signed_in_root_path(resource_or_scope)
  end
```

`signed_in_root_path` will look for `user_root_path`, `root_path` and then fall back to `"/"`.

Since this is a relative path it will always redirect back to the same subdomain that the request came from.

You need to alter the redirect after sign in to use an absolute URL:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  stored_location_for(resource) || root_url(subdomain: 'app')
end
```

This method can either be overridden in your ApplicationController (since Devise inherits from it) or by subclassing [Devise::RegistrationsController](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/f6e73e5b5c8f519f4be29ac9069c6ed8a2343ce4/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb).